# Delete line ending with a newline character in text file

Tags: macos, sed, terminal

I need to delete the same line in a large number of text files. I have been trying to use sed, but I cannot get it to delete the newline character at the end. The following successfully deletes the line, but not the newline:

```
sed -i -e 's/VERSION:1//' *.txt
```

I have tried using the following to delete the newline also, but it does not work:

```
sed -i -e 's/VERSION:1\n//' *.txt
```

Is there anyway to specify a newline in a sed substitute command OR is there any other command line tool I can use to achieve my goal? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sed` command:

```
sed -i -e '/VERSION:1/d'
```

for this.

The following transcript gives an example:

```
pax> echo 'hello
> goodbye
> hello again' | sed '/oo/d'
hello
hello again
```

You should also check whether you want to match whole lines with, for example:

```
sed -i -e '/^VERSION:1$/d'
```

since, as it stands, that will also delete lines like the following:

```
VERSION:10
CONVERSION:1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/VERSION:1/{:q;N;s/VERSION\n//g;t q}' file
```